Php or javascript libraries for GIS calculations
I am presently doing all my computing in QGIS.  Once all complete I export my point, line and polygon data in geojson for ultimate use with MapBox and Leaflet. I would like to automate my calculation as they are quite repetitive.  Also, as the end product is an online map, I would prefer something that can run via browser like php or javascipt.
Here are some of the calculations I run.  Any suggestions for suitable packages very welcome.

count how many lines in a polygon and add to polygon properties
add the length of each line in meters and add it to each line property
add the sum of all lengths and add it to the polygon property
add the count of all lengths and add it to the polygon
add the polygon ID to all lines and points in that polygon
with the assistance of a tiff DEM, I get the max height and min height of each polygon
calculate the centroid of each polygon and add it the properties
calculate the average bearing of each polygon in degrees
calculate the average slope of a line
calculate the max slope of a line basis 10m segement.  An min slope.
dissolve lines (eg join 2 lines or more into 1 line based on a common value)

So far, I have found geophp and turf.js but not sure yet if capable of above calculations.

If you are open to using Python, all can be done with Geopandas and Rasterstats (or rasterio)

If you want to use javascript for geospatial calculations, as you already assumed Turf.js is probably something you want to have look at.  It can be used both using node.js as in your browser.  The documentation for in-browser usage can be found here: https://turfjs.org/docs/getting-started#in-browser
On the API page you can find a long list of possible calculations: https://turfjs.org/docs/api/along.  Most of the things you are looking for can be found in that list (directly of by combining multiple functions).
Turf.js is actively developed, the latest update to the geoPHP repository is 8 years old, so development seems to have stopped for that one. So Turf.js is probably a better choice in that regard.  The advantage is also that Turf.js will use the resources of the users computer and geoPHP will use the PHP server's resources, that are probably rate limited if it's not your own server.
